# PowerMock doesnt stub when returning false

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, powermockito

I have this function to create a mocked Category class.

```
@Mock Category child;
@Mock OwnableHelper ownableHelper;

private Category getTreeRoot(boolean isOwnedBy) {

    Category category = mock(Category.class);
    when(category.getChildren()).thenReturn(new RealmList<>(child));

    when(ownableHelper.isOwnedBy(any(Ownable.class), any(HasId.class))).thenReturn(isOwnedBy);

    return treeRoot;
}
```

The tests are:

```
@Test(enabled = true)
public void RecursiveCallOnChildWithoutOwnOwnable() throws Exception {
    Category parent = getTreeRoot(false);
    ownableUpdater.updateRecursive(parent);
    verify(ownableUpdater).updateRecursive(child);
}

@Test(enabled = true)
public void DontCallRecursiveWhenChildHasOwnOwnable() throws Exception {
    Category parent = getTreeRoot(true);
    ownableUpdater.updateRecursive(parent);
    verify(ownableUpdater, never()).updateRecursive(child);
}
```

Now I want to test this code:

```
    for (Category child : category.getChildren()) {
        if (!ownableHelper.isOwnedBy(owner, child))
            updateRecursive(child);
    }
```

When I stub `ownableHelper.isOwnedBy()` with `true` the test does exactly what it should do. However if I pass `false` `category.getChildren()` throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at OwnableUpdater.updateRecursive(OwnableUpdater.java:72)
at RecursiveUpdaterTest.RecursiveCallOnChildWithoutOwnOwnable(RecursiveUpdaterTest.java:93)
```

and the Line 72 is `for (Category child : category.getChildren())`

How can stubbing something to false instead of true make another stub fail?

I do use testng 6.1.1 to run my tests and the Test extends from PowerMockTestCase.

Comment: How is initialized `ownableHelper`? Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Okay I updated the question.

Comment: You should define `child.getChildren()` too. Otherwise it will return null by default as you observed it

Comment: Thanks, that helped me.